# Selenium - Python Safari WebDriver - not finding element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to web-scrape https://trackingsdg7.esmap.org/country/bosnia-and-herzegovina in python using selenium web driver, but I have been running into issues grabbing the access to electricity, renewable energy, and access to clean cooking. I have tried several times to use driver.find_elements_by_xpath(), with the paths that I generated and those that Safari generates itself, but none of them seem to work.
Please help. I have gotten everything else from the website, but these are the most important numbers for my project.

Comment: Hi, could you put your code and the error stack here?

Comment: renewable_energy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-4"]/svg/g[3]/g/text/tspan').text

Comment: and I get a NoSuchElementException

Comment: Can you put your code & the stack trace in the question, so that it is clear what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to electricity:

```
//div[@id="country-pillar-1"]//*[local-name() = 'svg']//*[local-name()="text"]
```

Access to clean cooking:

```
//div[@id="country-pillar-2"]//*[local-name() = 'svg']//*[local-name()="text"]
```

Reneweable energy:

```
//div[@id="country-pillar-3"]//*[local-name() = 'svg']//*[local-name()="text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-4"]').text`